# How to omit responses for file.copy() in R?

Tags: r, file

I am using R notebook and need to copy a very large amount of files. However, when I run file.copy() on all my files, my notebook gets cluttered with responses like

```
$`***file_path***`
[1] TRUE
```

Is there a way to not show these responses when the files are successfully copied and only get the responses when it could not copy the file?

Answer (score 3):

To hide all results use `invisible(file.copy(<file_from>,<file_to>))`.

To still show `FALSE`, a possible solution (although 2 lines) is using `tryCatch`:

```
filecopy <- tryCatch(file.copy(<file_from>,<file_to>))
if(filecopy!=TRUE)print(filecopy)
```